# Update gdb breakpoints on run

Tags: gdb, breakpoints

GDB breakpoints won't work after the function address changed. Is it possible to tell gdb to relocate the function address when running the program?

Comment: gdb does do that.  How are you setting the breakpoint?  Can you show a small example?

Comment: thanks Tom, it was probably a bug, because I can't reproduce anymore..

Answer (score 0):

> GDB breakpoints won't work after the function address changed

That depends on *how* you set a breakpoint.

If you did `break *0x12345`, then you must update the breakpoint if on re-build and re-run the address you care about is different.

On the other hand, if you did `break foo`, and the `&foo` changes due to a re-build, GDB will automatically reset the breakpoint on the new address on re-run. (If GDB doesn't do it for you, that's a bug in GDB.)